# Change <img /> image with JavaScript Image object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript [Image object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) that I load dynamically with jQuery.

What I want to do is change a `<img />` image with one stored on my `Image` object. How should I do this?

Note: I want to avoid changing the source of my `<img />` tag as it downloads it again from the server, and I already have the image stored in my image object

Comment: Have you tried `$(image)`? Images are usually cached, so loading the same image twice won't download it twice.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you explain a bit more? I already know what `$(image)` does, but I have the image stored in a JavaScript `Image` object, and I want to avoid changing the src as I don't want to download the image every time I change it

Comment: Wrap your image object in the jQuery function. Images are cached, so re-downloading it usually doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I think the Image object only stores a reference to the image, not the image it's self.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean

```
$('#imageToChange').replaceWith(imageObject)
```

?

Comment: How can I do the same thing with only javascript and without jQuery?

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X - ask a question - you mean `document.querySelector("img").src=imageObject.src`?

Comment: No, I want to set a javascript object (`myImage = new image ()`) into a document html like` document.querySelector("img")=myImage`.

Comment: That does not make much sense to me. But ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

New Image object:

```
var Image_off = new Image();
Image_off.src = 'first.jpg';
```

image src change with jQuery:

```
$("#my_image").attr("src",Image_off.src);
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery...
have both images already on your page and show or hide either one, based on a logical condition.

Comment: Hmm, this might actually answer the underlying question rather than what the OP thought was the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your new image in javascript memory, and then append it after the original image, then remove the original. You may also wish to cache the original before removing it in case you would like to re-use it.

html

```
<img id="replace" />
```

js

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "someUri.png";
$("#replace").after(img);
$("#replace").remove();
```

Comment: How is this different than `$("#replace").prop('src', 'someUri.png')`?

Comment: Easier with `$('#replace').replaceWith(img);`, just saying.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - The OP said not to change the `src` is why I went that route.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté my thought exactly :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - I left it separate in case the OP wanted to save the replaced image before removing it (perhaps with clone).

Comment: Calling `.detach()` in the original is usually better in that case. `=]`